# Get items to list

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my code.

I am using the `wialon SDK` to develop an application
from this code, I can see the output from the system is printing the all available item, but I need to get this item into a list.

```
public void printUnitsNames(Item... items){
    if (items!=null && items.length>0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%d units found Printing their names...", items.length));
        for (Item item : items)
            System.out.println(String.format("\t%s", item.getName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe more. What is `Item` and which properties you need in list from `Item`?

Comment: 2018-10-15 10:44:25.280 12557-12917/net.atsuae.myapplicationwialon I/System.out: Search items is successful-:
2018-10-15 10:44:25.281 12557-12917/net.atsuae.myapplicationwialon I/System.out: 11 units found Printing their names...
2018-10-15 10:44:25.281 12557-12917/net.atsuae.myapplicationwialon I/System.out:  KCN-F46551
2018-10-15 10:44:25.282 12557-12917/net.atsuae.myapplicationwialon I/System.out:  KCN-F46956
2018-10-15 10:44:25.282 12557-12917/net.atsuae.myapplicationwialon I/System.out:  KCN-H67681

Comment: this is the items that i want to add in to a list

Comment: Hello if you can help me that which API you have used of wialon any details if you can share to me it wouuld more helpful, that i need to display Unit list and its details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which field you want to store in list from `Item` class. But check below code. Store **item name** in list like,

```
public void printUnitsNames(Item... items){
    List<String> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
    if (items!=null && items.length>0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%d units found Printing their names...", items.length));
        for (Item item : items)
        {
            allItems.add(item.getName());  
            System.out.println(String.format("\t%s", item.getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, this should be one line statement:

```
List<Item> itemsAsList = Arrays.stream(items).collect(Collectors.asList());
```

If you want specific values, use the `map` operator.

With versions below Java 8, you could always use `Arrays.asList(items)` to get the same result.

The reason I prefer Java 8 way of doing this is because of the `map` operator that allows one object to be transformed to another.